# How to change font color of keywords in excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a large set of text data and a list of keywords relating to that dataset. I process the data in python, generate a pandas dataframe and export it to xlsx for excel.

In the spreadsheet, I need to change the font color of the keywords to red. The keywords are typically substrings inside the cell. Is there a way in pandas to mark the keyword such that excel will recognize and change the font color of the keywords, or is there a way in excel to search for the keywords and change the font color?

Comment: How are you currently exporting to excel?

Comment: Just with pandas.DataFrame().to_excel().

Comment: Do you want to highlight individual words in cells or the cells containing the words?

Comment: Individual words in the cells.

Comment: I think what you want is write_rich_text from xlsxwriter - https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_rich_strings.html

Comment: That's really interesting, thank you norie!